# Finding the feature map corresponding to a specific Kernel? (Polynomial Kernels)

Tags: kernel-trick

I am just getting into machine learning and I am kind of confused about how to show the corresponding feature map for a kernel. For example, how would I show the following feature map for this kernel? $K(x,y) = (x \cdot y)^3 + x \cdot y$
Any help would be appreciated. Where x and y are in 2d x = (x1,x2) y = (y1,y2)

Thank you.

Comment: Still struggling to wrap my head around this problem, any help would be highly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I understand you ask about $K(x, y) = (x\cdot y)^3 + x \cdot y$ Where dot denotes dot product. Then

$K(x, y) = \phi(x) \cdot \phi(y)$

Where $\phi(x) = (\phi_{poly_3}(x^3), x)$

By $\phi_{poly_3}$ I mean polynomial kernel of order 3. You can find definitions for such kernels online.

In general if $K$ is a sum of smaller kernels (which $K$ is, since $K(x,y) = K_1(x, y) + K_2(x, y)$ where $K_1(x, y) = (x\cdot y)^3$ and $K_2(x, y) = x \cdot y$)

your feature space will be just cartesian product of feature spaces of feature maps corresponding to $K_1$ and $K_2$

$K(x, y) = K_1(x, y) + K_2(x, y) = \phi_1(x) \cdot  \phi_1(y) + \phi_2(x),\cdot \phi_2(y) =  \phi(x) \cdot  \phi(y) $

Where $\phi(x) = (\phi_1(x), \phi_2(x))$ (I mean concatenation here, so that if $x_1 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and  $x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^m$, then $(x_1, x_2)$ can be naturally interpreted as element of $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$).

Comment: And this doesn't change if our input vectors x and y and in 2d? x = (x1,x2) and y (y1,y2)?

Comment: No, you get different equation then. You can get the general form from [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10534/deriving-feature-map-formula-for-inhomogeneous-polynomial-kernel)

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but I'm still totally lost as to how to apply this formula to get our required kernel? In our case d = 2, however, what are Alpha and z^alpha values?

Comment: Please use latex for your questions. Before my edit it wasn't clear whether you meant dot product or standard 1D multiplication.